# Next test(s) ignored when afterMethod fails

Tags: java, testng

I want to continue test execution even if the `afterMethod` fails, is there any solution for that? I tried to use `alwaysRun = true`, but only before and after methods are executed, the tests are always ignored.

Here is a simple example (used assertion only for failing the test, imagine instead of assertion some logic which can fail), where the afterMethod fails and the rest tests are ignored.

```
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;

public class Test1 {

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("firstTest");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("secondTest");
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        System.out.println("thirdTest");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void clearData() {
        assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the question makes sense, but as an example you could throw new RuntimeException()  in clearData() instead of assertion.
I wonder if this behaviour is documented by testng ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use soft assertions (see for example https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/soft-asserts-in-testng-example)

Comment: It's just a simple example, My problem is not with assertion only, there can be other exceptions too

Comment: Have you considered catching those exceptions?

Comment: I did this way, but I want to find solution with TestNG

Answer (score 0):

You are using hard assertion. If you use softAssertion like below :

```
softAssertion.assertTrue(false);
```

In code :

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setup() {
    assertTrue(true);
}

@Test
public void test1() {
    System.out.println("firstTest");
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    System.out.println("secondTest");
}

@Test
public void test3() {
    System.out.println("thirdTest");
}

@AfterMethod
public void clearData() {
    SoftAssert softAssertion= new SoftAssert();
    softAssertion.assertTrue(false);
}
```

You should get this output :

```
firstTest
secondTest
thirdTest
PASSED: test2
PASSED: test3
PASSED: test1

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 3, Passes: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Please see here for [Reference](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/6.8.8/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.html)

Also, If you use `hard assertion` in a `@Test` not in `configuration annotation`, your test cases would have run if there was any failure.

But you are intentionally failing the testng `CONFIGURATION`, so when a configuration fails in testng next or other configuration are gonna be skipped, You may be seeing this kind of output.

```
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setup
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod clearData
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod clearData
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod setup
```